# How to apply same event to multiple buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to "toggle" information shown after button clicks.  I have multiple buttons that when each on is clicked, I want to either show or hide a block of text.

Unfortunately right now, when I click one button, it shows or hides ALL of the text blocks instead of just one.

This is the first script I have ever written on my own so please excuse me if I am using the incorrect syntax, but this is what I could figure out was necessary to use instead of toggle (as it is deprecated).

Here is my script:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="headCustomScriptsCSS" runat="server">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('button').click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
                    $('p').show();
                    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                } else {
                    $('p').hide();
                    $(this).addClass("clicked");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Some of my HTML code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>
        Add a New Application</h1>
    <h3>
        General Description</h3>
    <div>
        <div class="column-left">
            <label for="EnglishShortName">
                English Short Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-center">
            <input type="text" name="EnglishShortName" />
        </div>
        <div class="column-right">
            <button type="button" class="myButton">
                ?</button>
        </div>
        <div class="help">
            <p>
                This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs. You should feel lucky to have seen such a paragraph in your life. Congratulations! </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="column-left">
            <label for="FrenchShortName">
                    French Short Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-center">
            <input type="text" name="FrenchShortName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="column-left">
            <label for="ApplicationCode">
                Application Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-center">
            <input type="text" name="ApplicationCode" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="column-right">
            <button type="button" class="myButton">
                ?</button>
        </div>
        <div class="help">
            <p>
                This is a paragraph much like the last one.  It is a paragraph to end all paragraphs. You should feel lucky to have seen such a paragraph in your life. Congratulations! </p>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

and some of my CSS:

```
.column-left
{
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.column-right
{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
.column-center
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.help
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left:25%;
    border:1px dotted black;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

I have multiple more buttons like this that show and hide text.  My question is, how do I get the event to be handled separately for each button?  Do I need to have multiple scripts written?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('p').show()` is going to find **ALL** the `<p>` tags in your document. If you want only the one (or few) associated with the actual click, you'll have to narrow down the search.

Comment: `$('p')` returns all `p` elements on the page, so `$('p').show();` says "show all P elements on the page". You need to do some DOM tree traversal.

Comment: I understand that I am applying this to all 'p' tags, but I was wondering how I do this without duplicating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('p').show();
```

You're getting all p elements and showing them.

But to do what you want you need to navigate to get the right help element.

A fast way to fix your code is just change two lines:
1

```
$('p').show();
```

by

```
$(this).parent().next().show();
```

2

```
$('p').hide();
```

by

```
$(this).parent().next().hide();
```

It'll do what you want.

Comment: Amazing!  How does it understand which button I am clicking though?  I don't quite understand the logic behind it.

Comment: When you click on a button, this will become that button. After that, what you can do is navigate through the DOM and get the next help after that button. To do that, I used parent() to get the father of that button, after that I used next() to get the next sibling to show/hide. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/yx5r9/)**

```
   $('button').click(function () {
       pParent = $(this).parent().siblings(".help");
        if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
            $('p',pParent).show();
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        } else {
            $('p',pParent).hide();
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's weird, it works perfectly in JSFiddle and does exactly what I want, but it doesn't work at all for web app.  Am I using the wrong version of JQuery(1.10.1)?  Or could it be a problem because my site is using a master page?